# JavaFx: IntegerProperty.integerProperty() strange behavior

Tags: properties, bind, javafx-8

In a my view I have an `HBox`

```
@FXML
private HBox hboxWarning;
```

and I want hide/show it according to the value of

```
private ObjectProperty<Integer> maxClientCount;
```

If `maxClientCount > 10` then `hboxWarning` is visible else it's hide.
I bound the two elements in this way

```
hboxWarning.visibleProperty().bind(IntegerProperty.integerProperty(maxClientCount).greaterThan(10));
```

and works well. My problem is that

```
IntegerProperty.integerProperty(maxClientCount)
```

sets to zero the current value of `maxClientCount`. Is it a JavaFx bug or I'm using `IntegerProperty.integerProperty` improperly? And 
how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: it's a bug: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-37523

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be not as easy as assumed: the core fix needs additional methods in BidirectionalBinding to cope with the swapped sequence of number types. The actual number bindings are private, so no way to access in workaround code.

```
// method in u5, binds the wrong way round 
// (for usage in IntegerProperty.integerProperty) 
public static BidirectionalBinding bindNumber(Property<Integer> property1, 
       IntegerProperty property2) 

// calls 
private static <T extends Number> BidirectionalBinding bindNumber(Property<T> property1, 
       Property<Number> property2) {
```

The sequence is crucial because we need a type-cast from Number to T when setting the value of p1 (which is safe because we know that the number-type property copes with conversion from Number -> concrete type). Core fix simply adds all those methods with switched parameter sequence.

For a custom hack until the release of JDK 8u20, the only way I see is to not use the special number binding methods but the generic object binding:

```
public static IntegerProperty integerProperty(final Property<Integer> property) {
    if (property == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Property cannot be null");
    }
    return new IntegerPropertyBase() {
        {
            bindBidirectional(cast(property));
            // original:
            //BidirectionalBinding.bindNumber(property, this);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getBean() {
            return null; // Virtual property, no bean
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return property.getName();
        }

        @Override
        protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
            try {
                unbindBidirectional(cast(property));
                // original
                // BidirectionalBinding.unbindNumber(property, this);
            } finally {
                super.finalize();
            }
        }
    };
}

/**
 * Type cast to allow bidi binding with a concrete XXProperty (with
 * XX = Integer, Double ...). This is (?) safe because the XXProperty
 * internally copes with type conversions from Number to the concrete
 * type on setting its own value and exports the concrete type as
 * needed by the object property.
 * 
 */
private static <T extends Number> Property<Number> cast(Property<T> p) {
    return (Property<Number>) p;
}
```

Take it with a grain of salt - while rudimentarily tested, there might be side-effects I overlooked.

Comment: Thanks @kleopatra. I don't understand very well why the unchecked cast can be considered safe :-)

Comment: we are only interested in the value that's synched in the binding, done via setValue/getValue. Then T must be the type of the concrete number type, that is IntegerProperty <-> ObjectProperty<Integer>, or DoubleProperty <-> ObjectProperty<Double> to be safe for the other

Comment: Your workaround works!! Why compiler gives me "unchecked" warning in the cast method? Number is superclass of T... :/

Answer (score 1):

As rightly said by @kleopatra this is a JavaFx [bug](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-37523) fixed in JDK 8u20.

Meanwhile I used the following workaround:

```
int maxClients = maxClientCount.get();
hboxWarning.visibleProperty().bind(IntegerProperty.integerProperty(maxClientCount).greaterThan(10));
maxClientCount.setValue(maxClients);
```

I hope this can help someone.

Comment: my preference would be to not use the factory at all - c&p, fix the adapter and use that until the fix is released. Allowing the broken property to set and then revert it might pose problems with a) potential listeners (they'll get unexpected notifications) b) the adapted property itself (the adapter's set might break internal validation rules) As with all bug workarounds, it's a matter of taste, though :)

Comment: I agree with you that my workaround could create problems. I would follow your advice but I don't understand what should I copy and paste and then modify? IntegerProperty class?

Comment: IntegerProperty.integerProperty is a static method that internally wraps an IntegerProperty around your Property<Integer> - c&p that method and invert all bind(property, this) to bind(this, property)

Comment: ahh .. now I see why the bug happened in the first place (having only detected it, never tried to fix it myself) - the generic typing stands int the way. Will look at the fix in b20 and then come back